# In my query not return anything in codeigniter.This code is working but not give any result

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php     
//image formation
$imag_sel=$this->db
->select('image')
->where(['id',$id1])
->get('borrow_user');

$fil=$imag_sel->result();//result for code
print_r($fil);//return image but not returning anthing it's gave "array()"
?>
```

Comment: put $imag_sel=$this->db
            ->select('image')
            ->where('id',$id1)
            ->get('borrow_user'); in your code or check query is id exist in table or not

Comment: `$imag_sel` this is your instance? or `$this->db` ?

Comment: thanks abhijit for your comment i got an answer . by using this code                                            $arr=array('id'=>$id1);
                       $imag_sel=$this->db
                                      ->select('image')
                                    ->where($arr)
                                    ->get('borrow_user');
                       $fil=$imag_sel->result();

                      print_r($fil);

Comment: just return image due to this `select('image')`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, the issue was the "where" clause.

Where's can be done two ways:

Method 1:

```
->where('field', $value)
```

You chain together where clauses, e.g:

```
$this->db
  ->where('name', $name)
  ->where('age', $age)
  ->get('table');
```

or alternatively using an array.

Method 2:

```
$where = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'age' => $age,
);
$this->db
  ->where($where)
  ->get('table');
```

You also don't NEED to chain them. You can do them procedural:

```
$this->db->where('name', $name);
$this->db->where('age', $age);
// or
$this->db->where($where);

$this->db->get('table');
```

The first one is cleaner if you have a single where clause, however with multiple it's nicer to use the array (and also allows dynamic array building if required)

Comment: we can use both of where clause method in any time .

Comment: Improved answer for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
->where(['id',$id1])
```

to

```
->where('id',$id1)
```

Comment: I  think this will show an error  ->where(['id',$id1) this is not right syntax .

Comment: @HarshJain this one is also a possible syntax. I think you made the mistake because of `]` after `$id1`.